# cant find any RSS feed for new/updated questions

Tags: feature-request

I cant find any RSS feed for new/updated questions (same as SO).
Is it not available in Beta ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be on the bottom of the homepage, it links to https://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds

Are you talking about something else?

Comment: thanks for reply. I was checking on the home page :-).
RSS feed is tags basis. 
Just learnt something new :-)

Comment: I don't think it was there when the site first went beta... I looked for it, and the browser usually shows an icon when it's there and it wasn't at first. Now it is.